# Log4j2 SMTPAppender not sending email

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2, smtpappender

My question is similar to these two:

- [Log4j2: SMTPAppender does not send mails with error or fatal level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17657983/log4j2-smtpappender-does-not-send-mails-with-error-or-fatal-level)
- [How to send email notifications with slf4j / log4j2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19122295/how-to-send-email-notifications-with-slf4j-log4j2)

but I am not able to send SMTPs at all, and I do not want to put the `<appender-ref ref="SMTPAppender" />` inside the root logger. If i did, i would receive emails from every logger. So the SMTPAppender is able to send SMTPs but I just want the **notificationLogger** to be the only logger sending emails.

Here is my log4j2.xml file:

```
    <loggers>
        <logger name="notificationLogger" level="fatal" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="SMTPAppender" /> 
            <appender-ref ref="stdout" />
        </logger>
        <logger name="com.prod" level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="RollingFile"/>
        </logger>
        <root level="INFO">
            <appender-ref ref="stdout"/>
        </root>
    </loggers>
```

What do i do in order to have the **notificationLogger** be the only logger sending SMTPs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to update my maven dependencies to fix a known bug.

```
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.0-beta9</version>
  </dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not an expert on this but...

Isn't this a known bug?

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-310

Comment: I don't think this is the same bug. I did similar test cases to see if i had the same problem, but i didn't. First, i am not using the same environment, and secondly, i don't receive any SMTPs regardless of whether an info or fatal event occurred.